# How to split apache logfile per Month

Tags: linux, apache

I have a quite large apache logfile (2,5 G).
Its that big because i havent used logrotate until now.
Now the logs get rotated corretly but i want the rotation (one logfile per month) for the time until now so i have to "rotate" the old logfile.

Does anyone know how i could do that ? (some script that splits my logfile per month ?)

Thanks in advance,

Nicolas

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk` to find the month boundaries, then use `csplit` to split by context.

#### sample data:

```
1-1  ...
1-15 ...
1-30 ...
2-1  ...
2-15 ...
2-29 ...
3-2  ...
3-20 ...
```

#### run command

```
$ cat log | awk -F- 'x!=$1{x=$1; print "MONTH"}1' | csplit - /MONTH/ '{*}'
```

#### delete first line

```
$ sed -i 1d xx*
```

Answer (score 1):

LoadModule log_rotate_module modules/mod_log_rotate.so

CustomLog site.%m-.access.log

http://www.sitebuddy.com/mod_log_rotate